# Multilingual Approach in ASP.Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, resource-files

I have Asp.net page which contains Labels. I want to implement **Label** as **multilingual**. I have 2 approaches(There may be more):

**1: Use Text property as**

```
<asp:Label id="some_id" Text="Resources.ResourceFile.ResourceKey" runat="server" />
```

And Second Approach is

2: **Override Label control** or create custom control and expose a key which will accept Resource key and Replace all the Label with this Custom control.

Please let me know, which is the best approach and why?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you should take a look at this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334820/Using-Globalization-and-Localization-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's good but my question is, i should use meta:resource or should i ovverride Label control? Which is better approach?

Comment: Since there is already a built in capability of asp.net that allows you to do what you want I would say you should use it instead of implementing a custom label.